# add element to ngfor dom based on index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to render DIV element based on index and I don't want DIV to render all the ngfor "items". Is it also possible for to have Dynamic Content in DIV based on Index. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i =index">
    <i (click)="add(i)">
    <div *ngIf="i">

    </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a dynamic content in your div based on the index, you just need to use *ngIf as you already provide in your example :

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <i (click)="add(i)">
    <div *ngIf="i === 0">
        Content for the first index
    </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The div will only be present in the DOM for the first index.

You can also bind a value with `{{ }}` based on the `i` property provided as argument.